# Redux dispatch actions in response to actions

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming, redux

I'm thinking through some scenarios surrounding redux and I wasn't able to find a clean solution to this example:

Let's say you have a component that is a list of recipes. When you select a recipe from that list, you `dispatch(RECIPE_SELECTED)`. That async action-creator may do additional related to the recipe - perhaps go async fetch the ingredients for the recipes, save the selection to the server, whatever.

In a totally separate component you have a list of professional chefs. The desired behavior is that when a user selects a recipe, you populate the list of professional chefs with any chef who has a variation of the selected recipe.

How do you listen for `RECIPE_SELECTED` and then dispatch a totally unrelated action that has a dependency on the recipe? Something like...

```
when RECIPE_SELECTED:recipe
  loadChefs(recipe).then(res => dispatch(CHEFS_LOADED, res.chefs))
```

You *could* mix this `loadChefs/dispatch` into the action-creator of `RECIPE_SELECTED`, but that's a really gross mixing of concerns and will quickly weave a tangled web.

You could also do some very imperative (i.e. against the grain for redux) stuff like so (using React):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (nextProps.recipe !== this.props.recipe) {
    const { dispatch, recipe } = nextProps
    dispatch(loadChefs(recipe))
  }
}
```

I really don't like either of these solutions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

Are you familiar with redux-thunk?
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

With redux-thunk applied as middleware, you can do something like this:

```
function selectRecipe(recipe) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(setRecipe(recipe));
        return loadChefs(recipe).then((res) =>
            dispatch(setChefs(res.chefs))
        );
    };
}
```

Where `setRecipe` and `setChefs` are simple action creators. e.g.

```
function setRecipe(recipe) {
    return {
        type: SET_RECIPE,
        recipe
    };
}

function setChefs(chefs) {
    return {
        type: SET_CHEFS,
        chefs
    };
}
```

I recommend reading the docs on Async Actions.
https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions

Comment: I think you skimmed my question too fast: "You could mix this loadChefs/dispatch into the action-creator of RECIPE_SELECTED, but that's a really gross mixing of concerns and will quickly weave a tangled web." One of the main goals was to avoid mixing concerns across modules. Why does the `selectRecipe` creator have to know that it should also do a `loadChefs`? It shouldn't. That's mixing entirely separate domains into the same action creator... which means further down the road you're going to have an action creator in one module that holds domain knowledge about dozens of other modules.

Comment: I don't agree. If choosing a new recipe results in loading in a list of chefs then they are not separate concerns. There is no such thing as an action listener in redux. Any complex logic (especially async stuff) belongs in your action creator. What you can do is separate them into simple and complex action creators, as show above.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution is to use the [Redux-Saga](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) middleware. This lets you write something like this:

```
function* loadChefsSaga() {
    # takeLatest sets up a system that spawns the inner generator every time
    # an action matching the pattern is dispatched. If the inner generator
    # is still running when additional actions are dispatched, it is cancelled,
    # and a new one is spawned.
    yield takeLatest('RECIPE_SELECTED', function* (recipe) {
        # When a Promise is yielded, the generator is resumed when the Promise
        # resolves. Alternatively, if it rejects, the rejected value is thrown
        # into this generator.
        const {chefs} = yield loadChefs(recipe)

        # Assuming chefsLoaded is an action creator for CHEFS_LOADED
        # `put` is redux-saga's equivelent of `dispatch`. We use it because
        # the saga doesn't have direct access to the `dispatch` function.
        yield put(chefsLoaded(chefs))
    })
}
```

I'm assuming that you have a basic familiarity with how javascript generators work. If not, go look them up; they're a powerful pattern. In this case, redux-saga uses them to construct functions that can block on things. Every time something is yielded, redux-saga treats it as an "Effect" that it knows how to process. For instance, when a `Promise` is yielded, redux-saga sets it up so that the generator is resumed when the Promise resolves (or something is thrown into the generator if it rejects).